# How to export After Effect face tracking data?

Tags: tracking, movie, after-effects, face

Is there any way to output the face tracking data that generated by AE?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lQuKO.png)

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [help](https://helpx.adobe.com/after-effects/using/facetracking.html) reveals that it is normal keyframe data. So yes you can export them, but there is no build in way to do that. It could be done by scripting.